# How I control format folder with regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have to a project about folder processing and I want to control folder format true or false like

```
CustomerFile-2015-07-30T1510.txt
```

How can I do with regex?

This function all return false?

```
 public bool validateFileExpression()
    {
        var regExp = @"-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{4}\.txt$";
        var fileName = "d:\\CustomerFile-2015-07-30T1510.txt";
        Regex regex = new Regex(regExp);
        if (regex.IsMatch(fileName))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here, or exactly what tools you're using. Perhaps edit the question to make this clearer?

Comment: @AJFaraday I want to check folder format like some name - date and .txt
this is true or false return function

Comment: And which language do you plan to use?

Comment: @Arturo My project's language is c#

Comment: @MrtDev: [The method returns true.](http://ideone.com/5PJtqV)

Answer (score 0):

If files always have the literal "CustomerFile", and the date in the same format,

```
^CustomerFile-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{4}\.txt$
```

**Edit: new criteria specified in question**
Provided the only condition to check is that it ends with a date in the given format,

```
-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{4}\.txt$
```

Comment: @Marino Literal is changeable

Comment: If any character is allowed, and all you have to test is it ends with a date `-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{4}\.txt$`

Comment: Can you edit your question to specify the conditions that should be met?

Comment: @Marino First of all thanks for your answer I edit my question.This function all return false.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code you added. It returns true. [Check online](http://rextester.com/XBOTYX73057)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions. (not directly related to your regex, which looks correct by the way).

(1) don't create the Regex object over and over, this will slow you down if you are calling this method a lot.

(2) you can just return the result of the check: no need for `if`.

```
const string _regExp = @"-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{4}\.txt$";
Regex _regex = new Regex(_regExp);

public bool validateFileExpression(string fileName)
{
    return _regex.IsMatch(fileName);
}
```

I know it's only a demo code and probably none cares, but I though something good might come out of it..